# How to add filtering to custom table field column in Customers admin grid in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, grid, filter

Added custom columns from custom table to **Customers** grid using JOIN in the following method:

```
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection::_beforeLoad:
```

```
protected function _beforeLoad()
{
    ...
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('core_collection_abstract_load_before', ['collection' => $this]);
    ...
}
```

and by subscribing to the following event:

```
 
core_collection_abstract_load_before
```

To make custom columns to appear in the Customers grid we are using custom

```
 
view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml
```

file in our module:

```
<columns name="customer_columns">
    <column name="prxgtDwnlParentId">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="prxgtDwnlCustomerDepth">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Depth</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Everything is working fine, but since we are using aliases for field names filtering is not working.

We came up with the following dirty hack to make it work, basically through reverse transformation *"alias" => "table.field":*

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    ...
    /* the dirty hack */
    $where = $query->getPart('where');
    $replaced = $this->_replaceAllAliasesInWhere($where);
    $query->setPart('where', $replaced);
    ...
}

protected function _replaceAllAliasesInWhere($where)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($where as $item) {
        $item = $this->_replaceAliaseInWhere($item, self::AS_FLD_CUSTOMER_DEPTH, self::AS_TBL_CUST, 'depth');
        $item = $this->_replaceAliaseInWhere($item, self::AS_FLD_PARENT_ID, self::AS_TBL_CUST, 'parent_id');
        $result[] = $item;
    }
    return $result;
}

protected function _replaceAliaseInWhere($where, $fieldAlias, $tableAlias, $fieldName)
{
    $search = "`$fieldAlias`";
    $replace = "`$tableAlias`.`$fieldName`";
    $result = str_replace($search, $replace, $where);
    return $result;
}
```

There should be much more elegant way of doing it. Please, advise.